# stretchmode doesnt work in gridview

Tags: android, android-gridview

I havedefined the gridview to 3 columns:

```
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/wallpaper_gridview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:numColumns="3"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"/>
```

Each item is define by this XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical">

  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/wallpaper_image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

when I add scaleType="fitXy" property to ImageView this is the picture i get:
[image: image2]

I want width to be defined by number of columns and height to be in relation to the width. I am using Google's tutorial [1]: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html . I can overcome the problem by changing the return value of calculateInSampleSize method to 1. This is not a solution because it means I'm not loading a smaller picture.

Answer (score -1):

By setting scaleType to fitXY you can clearly see that stretchMode works.

In the first screenshot ImageView is stretched, but the Images are in portrait orientation so you see black spaces.

What you probably want is to set scaleType to centerCrop.

Comment: nope. that gives me the same size as the second screenshot only that it cuts part of the pic

Comment: @JY2k now I got what you want. I'm not sure if it works, but try adding android:adjustViewBounds="true" attribute to ImageView.

Comment: It doesn't affect the size at all